# Filter object array based on attributes min and max value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to filter the following object array based on max or min values of `sales` attribute.

```
data = [
  { region: 'Central', state: 'North Dakota', sales: 920 },
  { region: 'Central', state: 'South Dakota', sales: 1317 },
  { region: 'East', state: 'West Virginia', sales: 1209 },
  { region: 'East', state: 'Maine', sales: 1270 },
  { region: 'South', state: 'South Carolina', sales: 8483 },
  { region: 'South', state: 'Louisiana', sales: 9219 },
  { region: 'West', state: 'Wyoming', sales: 1603 },
  { region: 'West', state: 'Idaho', sales: 4380 },
  { region: 'West', state: 'California', sales: 4571 }
];
```

Filter the array based the maximum and minimum value of `sales` attribute. I'm looking for the following result:

```
newData = [
  { region: 'Central', min: 'North Dakota', max: 'South Dakota' },
  { region: 'East', min: 'West Virginia', max: 'Maine' },
  { region: 'South', min: 'South Carolina', max: 'Louisiana' },
  { region: 'West', min: 'Wyoming', max: 'California' }
];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3):

Ciao, you could try to filter `data` for `region`, then calculate max and min and push found object in result array like this:

```js
let data = [
  { region: 'Central', state: 'North Dakota', sales: 920 },
  { region: 'Central', state: 'South Dakota', sales: 1317 },
  { region: 'East', state: 'West Virginia', sales: 1209 },
  { region: 'East', state: 'Maine', sales: 1270 },
  { region: 'South', state: 'South Carolina', sales: 8483 },
  { region: 'South', state: 'Louisiana', sales: 9219 },
  { region: 'West', state: 'Wyoming', sales: 1603 },
  { region: 'West', state: 'Idaho', sales: 4380 },
  { region: 'West', state: 'California', sales: 4571 }
];

let regions = ['Central', 'East', 'South', 'West'];

let result = [];

regions.forEach(region => {
   let dataFilter = data.filter(el => el.region === region);
   let max = Math.max(...dataFilter.map(el => el.sales));
   let min = Math.min(...dataFilter.map(el => el.sales));
   let dataMax = dataFilter.filter(el => el.sales === max )[0];
   let dataMin = dataFilter.filter(el => el.sales === min )[0];
   let objresult = {region: region, min: dataMin.state, max: dataMax.state};
   result.push(objresult);
})

console.log(result)
```

This is the version with dynamic regions:

```js
let data = [
      { region: 'Central', state: 'North Dakota', sales: 920 },
      { region: 'Central', state: 'South Dakota', sales: 1317 },
      { region: 'East', state: 'West Virginia', sales: 1209 },
      { region: 'East', state: 'Maine', sales: 1270 },
      { region: 'South', state: 'South Carolina', sales: 8483 },
      { region: 'South', state: 'Louisiana', sales: 9219 },
      { region: 'West', state: 'Wyoming', sales: 1603 },
      { region: 'West', state: 'Idaho', sales: 4380 },
      { region: 'West', state: 'California', sales: 4571 }
    ];

    let regions = new Set(data.map(el => el.region));

    let result = [];

    regions.forEach(region => {
       let dataFilter = data.filter(el => el.region === region);
       let max = Math.max(...dataFilter.map(el => el.sales));
       let min = Math.min(...dataFilter.map(el => el.sales));
       let dataMax = dataFilter.filter(el => el.sales === max )[0];
       let dataMin = dataFilter.filter(el => el.sales === min )[0];
       let objresult = {region: region, min: dataMin.state, max: dataMax.state};
       result.push(objresult);
    })

    console.log(result)
```

Comment: @NinaScholz When I see your solutions I always think: why I didn't thought about that? But then I read better your code and I start to think another thing: why I don't understand what she wrote? :) Anyway I want to say that on algorithms you are excellent (and it's not the first time I thuoght that)

Comment: why not ask, what you don't understand?

Comment: @NinaScholz Today I understood what you have done (took 10 minutes to understand but I got it :)). But I promise that next time I don't understand some I will ask you. Anyway also today... a reducer with a map... how did you thought that? You made an intermediate solution and then optimize or you wrote just like that?

Comment: it just to have a look to the problem, the first is to group by `region`, which is the best (fatsest) to use an O(1) access, supplied by an object or `Map`. the second is to keep the  `min` and `max` values. the second step is only to change the appearance of the result.

Answer (score 2):

You could group by `state` and get `min` and `max` states.

This approach takes a **single** loop for gathering the data.

```js
const
    data = [{ region: 'Central', state: 'North Dakota', sales: 920 }, { region: 'Central', state: 'South Dakota', sales: 1317 }, { region: 'East', state: 'West Virginia', sales: 1209 }, { region: 'East', state: 'Maine', sales: 1270 }, { region: 'South', state: 'South Carolina', sales: 8483 }, { region: 'South', state: 'Louisiana', sales: 9219 }, { region: 'West', state: 'Wyoming', sales: 1603 }, { region: 'West', state: 'Idaho', sales: 4380 }, { region: 'West', state: 'California', sales: 4571 }],
    result = Object
        .entries(data.reduce((r, { region, state, sales }) => {
            if (!r[region]) {
                r[region] = { min: { state, sales }, max: { state, sales } };
            } else if (r[region].min.sales > sales) {
                r[region].min.sales = sales;
                r[region].min.state = state;        
            } else if (r[region].max.sales < sales) {
                r[region].max.sales = sales;
                r[region].max.state = state;        
            }
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .map(([region, { min: { state: min }, max: { state: max } }]) => ({ region, min, max }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce and create an object with `region` as code. Then add value to that key and while adding check for the max and min with respective to current object. In the sales is greater or lesser than than max and min value , then replace the object data

```js
data = [{
    region: 'Central',
    state: 'North Dakota',
    sales: 920
  },
  {
    region: 'Central',
    state: 'South Dakota',
    sales: 1317
  },
  {
    region: 'East',
    state: 'West Virginia',
    sales: 1209
  },
  {
    region: 'East',
    state: 'Maine',
    sales: 1270
  },
  {
    region: 'South',
    state: 'South Carolina',
    sales: 8483
  },
  {
    region: 'South',
    state: 'Louisiana',
    sales: 9219
  },
  {
    region: 'West',
    state: 'Wyoming',
    sales: 1603
  },
  {
    region: 'West',
    state: 'Idaho',
    sales: 4380
  },
  {
    region: 'West',
    state: 'California',
    sales: 4571
  }
];
let newData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  // check if in accumulator object have a key same as region code.
  if (!acc[curr.region]) {
    // create a key and add value ,maxVal and minVal will be used to compare sales
    acc[curr.region] = {
      region: curr.region,
      min: curr.state,
      max: curr.state,
      maxVal: curr.sales,
      minVal: curr.sales
    }
  }
  if (curr.sales > acc[curr.region].maxVal) {
    acc[curr.region].max = curr.state;
    acc[curr.region].maxVal = curr.sales;
  }

  if (curr.sales < acc[curr.region].minVal) {
    acc[curr.region].min = curr.state;
    acc[curr.region].minVal = curr.sales;
  }
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(newData))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newData = [];

for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  const matchedRegion = newData.findIndex((e) => e.region === data[i].region);
  if(matchedRegion !== -1){
    const min = data.find((f) => f.state === newData[matchedRegion].min).sales;
    const max = data.find((f) => f.state === newData[matchedRegion].max).sales;
    if(data[i].sales < min){
      newData[matchedRegion].min = data[i].state;
    } else if(data[i].sales > max){
      newData[matchedRegion].max = data[i].state;
    }
  } else {
    newData.push({region: data[i].region, min: data[i].state, max: data[i].state});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nasty oneliner-esque you can use:

```js
let data = [
  { region: 'Central', state: 'North Dakota', sales: 920 },
  { region: 'Central', state: 'South Dakota', sales: 1317 },
  { region: 'East', state: 'West Virginia', sales: 1209 },
  { region: 'East', state: 'Maine', sales: 1270 },
  { region: 'South', state: 'South Carolina', sales: 8483 },
  { region: 'South', state: 'Louisiana', sales: 9219 },
  { region: 'West', state: 'Wyoming', sales: 1603 },
  { region: 'West', state: 'Idaho', sales: 4380 },
  { region: 'West', state: 'California', sales: 4571 }
];

let newData = Array.from(new Set(data.map((item) => item.region)))
.map((region) => ({
    region: region,
    min: data.filter((item) => item.region == region).reduce((acc, cur) => cur.sales < acc.sales ? cur : acc, {sales: Infinity}).state,
    max: data.filter((item) => item.region == region).reduce((acc, cur) => cur.sales > acc.sales ? cur : acc, {sales: -Infinity}).state
}));

console.log(newData);
```